# Convert Form Filter to Where Clause

Tags: ms-access, vba

Trying to append contents of me.filter to the end of the query.

Getting 'syntax error in parameter clause' yet when I take the results of ?qdf.sql and place them in a regular query it works.

PARAMETERS par_car_id Long;
SELECT tool_tran.car_id, tool_tran.d008g, tool_tran.d046d INTO tmp_tbl_tool_export
FROM tool_tran;

```
On Error GoTo ErrTrap

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim strNewWHERE As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim i As Integer

If fnTableExists("tmp_tbl_tool_export") = True Then
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "tmp_tbl_tool_export"
Else
End If

Set dbs = CurrentDb

Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("qry_tmp_tbl_tool_export")

If Me.Filter <> "" Then
    strNewWHERE = " WHERE ((tool_tran.car_id)=[forms]![frm_select_car_universal]![txt_car_id]) AND " & Me.Filter
    strNewWHERE = Replace(strNewWHERE, "[", "")
    strNewWHERE = Replace(strNewWHERE, "]", "")
    strNewWHERE = Replace(strNewWHERE, "qry_tool_tran_expanded", "tool_tran")
Else
End If

'looks to append converted filter to end of query def

If strNewWHERE <> "" Then
    qdf.sql = Left(qdf.sql, InStr(qdf.sql, ";") - 1) & strNewWHERE & ";"
Else
    qdf.sql = Left(qdf.sql, InStr(qdf.sql, ";") - 1)
End If

qdf.Parameters("par_car_id") = [Forms]![frm_select_car_universal]![txt_car_id]

qdf.Execute
qdf.Close

Set qdf = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*SQL* run from *VBA* doesn't know about an open form, so you must include the value itself from the form:

```
strNewWHERE = " WHERE ((tool_tran.car_id)=" & [forms]![frm_select_car_universal]![txt_car_id].Value & ") AND " & Me.Filter
```

Comment: I see how your post improves things but still getting error.  I think I know why based on what you said.

Comment: I am afraid this approach is not going to work.  The query has multiple joins so there is no way of finding the correct table name to prefix the field name in the where statement.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, but the table name needs only to be prefixed if the field name is not unique - which it always can be using an alias in the query.

Comment: The idiot that designed this database did not use unique keys.  The field names are repeated throughout the 6 tables in the query.  I will try using aliases.  I wish there was a way to have me.filter show the table name the field came from.

Comment: Alias not working.  Pulling plug on this.  Too much time into it.  Other duties call.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: So the solution here was simple.  Have QueryDef look at a temp table.  That way there is not field confusion.